# A Chinese Exam Question which is.....quite hard

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $f(x)=x^2-2x-3$, and $x_n$ be some sequence.

$x_1=2$, $x_n =$ the $x$ coordinate of the point of intersection of the $x$ axis and the line joining $P(4,5)$  and $Q_n(x_n, f(x_n))$.

Find an expression for $x_n$

Find $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} Q_n(x_n,f(x_n))$.

Comment: This is hard to read. Please format it correctly.

Comment: The definition of $x_n$ is self referential and doesn't make sense to me. Should $x_n$ be the x-coordinate of the intersection of $x$-axis with the line $PQ_{\color{red}{n-1}}$ instead?

Comment: Should that be $x_{n+1}= \dots$

Comment: What  is $Q_n$? Is it a function or a point?

Comment: Try to interpret the problem geometrically: the given function is a parabola; draw the parabola (where are its zeroes?) and localize P. Then you should get an idea on what is happening with the (recursively) defined points $Q_n$ - and where the limit is...

Answer (score 2):

The slope of the line connecting points $(4,5)$ and $(x_n,y_n)$ is $m_n=\dfrac{5-y_n}{4-x_n}$

So the equation of the line is

$\begin{equation}
 y-5=\dfrac{5-y_n}{4-x_n}(x-4)
 \end{equation}$

$x_{n+1}$ will be the point on this line for which $y=0$, so (omitting the algebra)

$\begin{eqnarray}
 x_{n+1}&=\dfrac{4x_n-4y_n}{5-yn}\\
        &=\dfrac{4x_n^2-13x_n-12}{x_n^2-2x_n-8}
 \end{eqnarray}$

In the limit we will have

$\begin{equation}
x=\dfrac{4x^2-13x-12}{x^2-2x-8}
 \end{equation}$

or

$\begin{eqnarray}
 x^3-6x^2+5x+12&=0\\
 (x+1)(x-3)(x-4)&=0
 \end{eqnarray}$

The sequence $\{x_n\}$ will never make it beyond 3 which is a zero of $f(x)$, so the limit of $Q_n$is $(3,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x):=x^2-2x-3=(x-3)(x+1)$ is zero at $x=3$ and the point $P=(4,5)$ lies on the graph of $f$. Note that the sequence $x_n$ starts at $x_1=2$, with $f(x_1)<0$.

The algorithm for generating the next term in the sequence is to draw the secant line from $Q_n:=(x_n,f(x_n))$ to $P$ and declaring $x_{n+1}$ to be the $x$-coordinate where this secant line intersects the $x$-axis. Expressing the slope of the secant line as rise-over-run, this gives an expression for $x_{n+1}$:
$${0-5\over x_{n+1}-4}={f(x_n)-5\over x_n-4}=x_n+2.$$
Rearranging, we get 
$$x_{n+1}-4={-5\over x_n+2}.$$
In view of what the algorithm is doing, we suspect that $x_n$ increases to 3 as $n\to\infty$. So define $y_n:=3-x_n$, which yields
$$y_{n+1}={y_n\over 5-y_n}$$
which can be rearranged to
$$\frac1{y_{n+1}}=\frac5{y_n}-1.$$
Defining $z_n:=\frac1{y_n}$, we have the recurrence
$$z_{n+1}=5z_n-1$$
which can be solved by guessing the solution $z_n=a5^n+b$. With the initial condition $z_1=1$, the solution is
$$z_n=\frac3{20}5^n+\frac14.$$
Unravel this to obtain a closed form for $x_n$, which indeed converges to 3, since $z_n\to\infty$ which implies $y_n\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean $x_1=2$ and $x_{n+1}=$ the $x$ coordinate of the point of intersection of the $x$ axis and the line joining $P(4,5)$ and $Q_n(x_n,f(x_n))$.

Now the equation of the line joining $Q_n(x_n,f(x_n))$ and $P(4,5)$ is
$$\frac{y-5}{x-4}=\frac{f(x_n)-5}{x_n-4}=\frac{x_n^2-2x_n-3-5}{x_n-4}$$

Setting $y=0$ to find $x_n+1$, we have
$$x_{n+1}-4=-\frac{5}{x_n^2-2x_n-8}(x_n-4)$$

Define $z_n=x_n-4$, we have $z_1=-2$ and
$$z_{n+1}=-\frac{5}{z_n+6}$$

Now, if $-2\le z_n\le-1$, one can show that $-2 \le z_{n+1} \le -1$ as well.

In particular, the $z_n$ sequence is bounded from above by $-1$.

Now consider
$$z_{n+1}-z_n=-\frac{5}{z_n+6}-z_n$$
$$=-\frac{(z_n+1)(z_n+5)}{z_n+6}$$

Since $-2 \le z_n \le -1$, we have
$$z_{n+1}-z_n \ge 0$$

So the $z_n$ sequence is non-decreasing and bounded from above and hence limit exists. We can then take the limit of both sides of
$$z_{n+1}=-\frac{5}{z_n+6}$$
to get
$$z=-\frac{5}{z+6}$$
which implies $z=-1$ ($z=-5$ rejected).

Hence,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=3$$